# Get all the rows that have unique values in a field, using sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

What options should I pass to `findAndCountAll` method of a sequelize model so that it returns the rows that have unique values in a certain field? In my particular case I need to get all the models that have unique `attack_id` field values.

`const { count, rows } = await myModel.findAndCountAll(?????);`

Answer (score 2):

```
const { count, rows } = await myModel.findAndCountAll({
attributes: [
        [sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', sequelize.col('attack_id')), 'attack_id'],
      ],
});
```

That's how I did it. But the count is incorrect, as it doesn't count the unique property.